# Pl/sql Error: Identifier 'Record' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am new to pl/sql. I am having a requirement to retrieve a row based on the given row id. For that I wrote a function that returns the row. This is the function that I have written.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECKROW(ROW_ID_ IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN TBL_SPT%ROWTYPE 
IS
  VAR_TEMP_ TBL_SPT%ROWTYPE;
  CURSOR GET_ROW IS
    SELECT *
    FROM TBL_SPT 
    WHERE ROWID = ROW_ID_;
BEGIN
    OPEN GET_ROW; 
    FETCH GET_ROW
    INTO VAR_TEMP_;
    --Here I wrote the print statement to get the id only. 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR_TEMP_.s_id);
    RETURN VAR_TEMP_;
    CLOSE GET_ROW;
END CHECKROW;
```

But when I test this function, it give the below error. My first question is why does this function give this error? I have used a cursor here. Is it wrong? Should I use a record?
The other question is, should I use 'VAR_TEMP_.id' type for all the fields if I want to print the records. Is there any other method?

[image: Error]

Here are my table definitions.

```
Name        Type   
----------- ------ 
S_ID        NUMBER                           
P_ID        NUMBER                           
PR_ID       NUMBER                           
QUANTITY    NUMBER                           
ROW_VERSION DATE
```

Here is the calling function that is produced when testing. `row_id_` is a string.

```
declare
  -- Non-scalar parameters require additional processing 
  result record;
begin
  -- Call the function
  result := checkrow(row_id_ => :row_id_);
end;
```

Comment: The error points to the line with either `select *` or `is`, which do not look relevant. Please, provide reproducible example with definitions of all the objects used (table definition, this function definition, the code calling this function).

Comment: If you are  - as appears - selecting one specific row as uniquely identified by your input parm, there is no need for a cursor at all.  A simple SELECT ... INTO will suffice.   I'd also urge a better naming convention than ending your parms and variables with an underscore.  Too easily missed when trying to eyeball/debug code.  Start your parms with a 'p_' prefix, and your local variables with a 'v_' prefix.

Comment: I believe that the `RETURN` statement must be the last statement in the function body.

Comment: `ROWID` is a pseudo column of data type `ROWID` (or more generic `UROWID` for Index-organized tables). You cannot compare with `VARCHAR2`

Comment: Error says "identifier RECORD must be declared". Your code does not contain any `RECORD`. Please provide valid code which matches the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from the anonymous block you have calling the function, not from the function itself; it isn't getting as far as actually making that call.

The declaration:

```
  result record;
```

should be:

```
  result TBL_SPT%ROWTYPE;
```

to match the function's return type. It looks like the boiler-plate code uses a generic 'record' which it expects you to define or replace. And as it says in a comment, "Non-scalar parameters require additional processing".

That doesn't mean that your function doesn't have issues, as noted in comments; but those aren't causing this error.

Comment: When I changed as above it worked. But, this calling function was generated automatically by the pl/sql developer. Is that mean, that I cannot trust the automatically proposed calling function?

Comment: It generates a very basic call as a starting point, but you have to modify it - you need to do something with the results, for example.

Comment: @Ann there are limits to what PL/SQL Developer can generate. When it hits something it can't handle, it gives the message about requiring additional processing - it means you have to code that part of the test script yourself.